# If I have two models and need a calculation on each attribute, should I calculate on the fly or create a 3rd model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models - `Score` & `Weight`.

Each of these models have about 5 attributes.

I need to be able to create a `weighted_score` for my `User`, which is basically the product of `Score.attribute_A` * `Weight.attribute_A`, `Score.attribute_B` * `Weight.attribute_B`, etc.

Am I better off creating a 3rd model - say `Weighted_Score`, where I store the product value for each attribute in a row with the `user_id` and then query that table whenever I need a particular `weighted_score` (e.g. `my_user.weighted_score.attribute_A`) or am I better off just doing the calculations on the fly every time?

I am asking from an efficiency stand-point.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is very situation-dependent.  Creating a 3rd table may be a good idea if the calculation is very expensive, you don't want to bog down the rest of the system and it's ok for you to respond to the user right away with a message saying that calculation will occur in the future.  In that case, you can offload the processing into a background worker and create an instance of the 3rd model asynchronously.  Additionally, you should [de-normalize the table](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1092433274582) so that you can access it directly without having to lookup the Weight/Score records.

Some other ideas:

1. Focus optimizations on the model that has many records.  If Weight, for instance, will only have 100 records, but Score could have infinite, then load Weight into memory and focus all your effort on optimizing the Score queries.
2. Use [memoization](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/59-use-memoization) on the calc methods
3. Use [caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) on the most expensive actions/methods.  if you don't care too much about how frequently the values update, you can explicitly sweep the cache nightly or something.

Comment: Thanks for the link on de-normalization. That's exactly what I am going to do. I just added a `weighted_score` attribute to my `User` model so that I am able to easily get the score I know my user needs. Then just update that periodically in the background like you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a need to store the calculated score (lets say that it changes and you want to preserve the changes to it) i dont see any benefit of adding complexity to store it in a separate table.

Comment: I am tempted to agree with you.